# Selector don't select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have many divs with `data-id="mbus"` attribute for example. When I try to select all of them using `$('tbody[data-id="mbus"]')` it always didn't select one of them.

Here's jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tumoxep/D9QbM/1/

Comment: Are you trying to select div or tbody elements? Or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine, but you have 2 `tbody` with this `data-id` and 1 `table`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Really sorry. Thanks. I'll remove this question.